# Spring r2dbc jOOQ transaction rollback not working

Tags: spring-boot, jooq, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc, r2dbc-postgresql

Transaction rollback does not seem to work when using r2dbc and jOOQ

DemoRepository

```kotlin
suspend fun insert(id: String) {
    if (id == "b") {
        throw RuntimeException("error while inserting")
    }

    db.insertInto(DEMO_TABLE)
        .set(DEMO_TABLE.ID, id)
        .awaitSingle()
}
```

DemoService

```kotlin
suspend fun addRecords(): Unit = transactionalOperator.executeAndAwait {
    log.info("Inserting records")
    repo.insert("a")
    repo.insert("b")  // throws error
}
```

and then

```kotlin
repo.getAll() // returns ["a"] instead of []
```

Full code: https://github.com/linktosriram/r2dbc-jooq-rollback

Even-though the inserts are done within a transaction, it does not seem to be rolled back when an exception is thrown

Logs:

```
Executing query: BEGIN READ WRITE
Executing query: insert into demo_table (id) values ($1)
Executing query: ROLLBACK
Executing query: select demo_table.id from demo_table
```

When swapping jOOQ `DSLContext` to `DatabaseClient` the rollback works. Looks like a bug in jOOQ

```kotlin
suspend fun insert(id: String) {
    if (id == "b") {
        throw RuntimeException("error while inserting")
    }

    dbClient.sql("insert into demo_table (id) values ('$id')")
        .fetch()
        .awaitSingle()
}
```

Comment: For the record, this question was cross posted here: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/16109